# MacBook Air m1 battery is draining very fast

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I’ve recently bought 2020 MacBook Air with M1 chip and battery life was incredible over the first couple of days. Then I decided to upgrade macOS to Big Sur 11.0.1 and now I wonder if the battery drain is actually ok.

I think it drains too fast now, faster than before. Maybe something went wrong during the update. It drained 4% in half an hour and all I was doing is scrolling couple of pages in Safari and some system settings.

Here are the screenshots:
[image: scrn2]

[image: scrn1]

Comment: Add some screenshots of Activity Monitor's i. CPU and ii. Energy pages sorted by highest. You can find Activity Monitor in Applications -> Utilities.

Comment: @Scottmeup I have added some screenshots about that.

Comment: Are you aware that 4% in half an hour should still be 12 hour battery life–marginally below Apple's rated battery life–and the difference could be something as small as screen brightness.

Comment: It is common (In my experience at least) for Macs to run a little hot after an OS upgrade as Spotlight is busy indexing the drive and other apps may be doing other things as a result of the upgrade. My Macs settle down after 2-3 days and return to normal. This **may** be happening to you.

Comment: Also keep an eye on the Memory tab. If you're like me and keep a million tabs open, Memory can go into the yellow/orange and red, then things slow to a crawl and the system uses a lot more power to manage things. However 4% doesn't sound so bad.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure completely quit apps by going into them and pressing Command + Q in your keyboard. Also, restart your MacBook. Plug it in and give it some time to index the drive and finish things. Then shutdown the Mac for 30 minutes and turn it back on. See if it helps.